# How composite signal in CDMA is normalise in general?

Tags: digital-communications, modulation

I had CDMA composite signal with 3 users. I assume that the signals are linearly sum together so for my maximum and minimum amplitude of composite signal are +3 and -3 respectively.

**Reference:**

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

from numpy import fft

def cconv(x, y):
    """Calculate the circular convolution of 1-D input numpy arrays using DFT
    From the Signal Processing Library: http://mubeta06.github.io/python/sp/filter.html
    """
    return fft.ifft(fft.fft(x)*fft.fft(y))

def ccorr(x, y):
    """Calculate the circular correlation of 1-D input numpy arrays using DFT
    From the Signal Processing Library: http://mubeta06.github.io/python/sp/filter.html
    """
    return fft.ifft(fft.fft(x)*fft.fft(y).conj())

def despread(composite, code, codelength):
    l = len(composite)//codelength
    despread = composite*(code*-2.0+1)
    recovered = []
    for i in range(l):
        recovered = np.append(recovered, 1.0*sum(despread[i*codelength:i*codelength+codelength])//codelength)
    recovered = np.repeat(recovered, codelength)
    return recovered


def bitfield(n):
    """Convert integer into bitfield (as list)
    From StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10322018/
    """
    return [int(digit) for digit in bin(n)[2:]] 


# Two Gold codes. See 
# Gold, R. "Optimal binary sequences for spread spectrum multiplexing (Corresp.)"
# IEEE Transactions on Information Theory. (October 1967)
g0 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int)
g30 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])

codelength = len(g0) # 2^8 - 1 = 255

# Primary user data
p = 0x91
p = np.array(bitfield(p))
p_len = len(p)
p = np.repeat(p, codelength)
p_code = []
for i in range(p_len):
  p_code = np.append(p_code, g30)

# First secondary user and his code
q = 0xc1
q = np.array(bitfield(q))
q_len = len(q)
q = np.repeat(q, codelength)
q_code = []
for i in range(q_len):
  q_code = np.append(q_code, g30)

q_spread = np.logical_xor(q_code, q).astype(int)

# Second secondary user and her code
r = 0xa5
r = np.array(bitfield(r))
r_len = len(r)
r = np.repeat(r, codelength)
r_code = []
for i in range(r_len):
  r_code = np.append(r_code, g0)

r_spread = np.logical_xor(r_code, r).astype(int)

# Composite sigal from all three users
composite = (p*2-1) + (r_spread*2-1) + (q_spread*2-1)

plt.plot(composite)
```

[image: CDMA composite signal]

```
#modulation
f = 25000
t=np.linspace(0,8/f,248)

carrier = lambda t: np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
#plt.plot(t,carrier(t),'b')
signal = lambda t: carrier(t) * composite
plt.plot(t,signal(t),color='red')
```

[image: Modulated_Composite_Signal]

How can i normalize my signal, generally its by number of users at receiver side. But for transmission, don't i need signal with +1 and -1 ? Am i missing something ? What would be the correct approach ?

Comment: the question is unclear: you're confusing your simulation with a real-world CDMA system, where none of the transmissions would ever reach you unattenuated, and "1" doesn't actually mean a physical quantity

Comment: The cell phone base station will generate one signal for each phone, sum them, and then amplify the result in a linear amplifier.  Not only are they not limited to $\pm 1$ at the output, but they'll also boost signals to phones that report poor reception, so there's not even a single amplitude that any phone might receive.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : How can i modulate this composite signal using any modulation technique i.e BPSK ? I am confused as my bits are not binary any more but for BPSK, one can multiply data_bit*carrrier ?